# Quiz app, change button color of wrong and correct answer on wrong answer selection, android

Tags: java, android, button

I am working on an android quiz app and I need to change the color of the buttons when a wrong answer is selected. I have it setup to already change the color if the button they select is wrong *OR* if the button they select is right. So what is the best way to ALSO change the color of the button with the correct answer when a incorrect answer is selected? If that makes sense. Basically I need to have 2 buttons that the color is changed when you select the wrong answer. Red for the wrong answer they selected and green for the right answer that they obviously did not select. Answers are shuffled as well so not sure how to tell which one is right.

Also try to spell things out and give me examples as I am just getting my feet wet in all of this! It is run in a fragment and if anyone has any pointers on how to streamline anything or fix bad code feel free to let me know as I am just starting to learn and need all the help I can get.

Here is my **onActivityCreated**

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    timesUp = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.times_up);
    timesUp.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    Bundle c;
    c = getArguments();
    String setCategory = c.getString("category");

    QuizHelper db = new QuizHelper(this.getActivity()); // my question bank class
    quesList = db.getAllQuestions(setCategory);  // this will fetch all quetonall questions

    currentQ = quesList.get(qid);

    txtQuestion = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.txtQuestion);
    // the textview in which the question will be displayed

    // the buttons,
    // the idea is to set the text of the buttons with the options from question bank
    button1 = (Button)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button2 = (Button)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button3 = (Button)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button3);
    button4 = (Button)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button4);

    //set buttons white
    button1.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    button2.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    button3.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    button4.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

    // the textview in which score will be displayed
    scored = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.score);
    scored.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.current_score, score));

    // the timer
    times = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.timers);

    // method which will set the things up for our game
    allAnswers.clear();
    setQuestionView();
    times.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.start_time));

    // Start timer
    timer.start();

    // button click listeners
    // passing the button text to other method
    // to check whether the answer is correct or not
    // same for all three buttons
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getAnswer(button1);
        }
    });

    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getAnswer(button2);
        }
    });

    button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getAnswer(button3);
        }
    });

    button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getAnswer(button4);
        }
    });

}
```

Here is my **getAnswer()** (shortened a bit)

```
public void getAnswer(TextView AnswerString) {

    String option = AnswerString.getText().toString();

    //If timer is running stop and restart
    if(timer != null) {
        timer.cancel(); // Stop Timer
        timer.start(); // Start timer
    }

    if (currentQ.getANSWER().equals(option)) {

        // if conditions matches increase the int (score) by 1
        // and set the text of the score view
        score++;
        scored.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.current_score, score));
        AnswerString.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    } else {

       //If answer is wrong change button colors

        AnswerString.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        //WrongAnswer.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                //Load ResultFragment()...                    

            }
        }, 1000);
        return;

    }
    if (qid < 25) {

        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                // if questions are not over then do this
                currentQ = quesList.get(qid);
                allAnswers.clear();

                //set all buttons white for next question
                button1.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                button2.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                button3.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                button4.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

                setQuestionView();

            }
        }, 1000);

    } else {

        // if "game over" (qid>25) do this
        //Load ResultFragment()...

}
```

and finally my **questionView()**

```
private void setQuestionView() {

    allAnswers.add(currentQ.getOPTA());
    allAnswers.add(currentQ.getOPTB());
    allAnswers.add(currentQ.getOPTC());
    allAnswers.add(currentQ.getOPTD());

    Collections.shuffle(allAnswers);

    txtQuestion.setText(currentQ.getQUESTION());
    button1.setText(allAnswers.get(0));
    button2.setText(allAnswers.get(1));
    button3.setText(allAnswers.get(2));
    button4.setText(allAnswers.get(3));

    qid++;
}
```

Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: how can you call `getAnswer(Button)` when it is only accepting `TextView` in `getAnswer(TextView)`

Comment: Because in `getAnswer(TextView AnswerString)` i am using `String option = AnswerString.getText().toString();` to change it into a string then i can use `option` to compare `currentQ.getANSWER().equals(option)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

You can get button text with :

```
// for currentQ.getANSWER().equals(option)
String option = selectedButton.getText();
```

**BEFORE EDIT**

*Call this from `getAnswer(Button selectedButton)` wrong answer field*

Get answer from your database and match it with `getText()` of all your buttons

```
// because you found out that selected answer/button was wrong
selectedButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

// take real answer from DB and store in String, probably you've already done this
String answerText = "take-answer-from-database";
```

**Option 1:**

```
//match DB answer to selected answer, turn it green if it is correct
if(button1.getText().equals(answerText)){
    button1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
} else if(button2.getText().equals(answerText)){
    button2.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
} else if(button3.getText().equals(answerText)){
    button3.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
} else if(button4.getText().equals(answerText)){
    button4.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
}
```

**Option 2:**

```
// match DB answer to selected answer, turn it green if it is correct
ArrayList buttonList = new ArrayList();
buttonList.add(button1);
buttonList.add(button2);
buttonList.add(button3);
buttonList.add(button4);

for(Button button : buttonList){
    if(button.getText().equals(answerText)){
        button.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        break;
    }
}
```

*Note: If your `getAnswer(Button)` is in different class, simply make your buttons global and `public` , Then, access them with their Class object*

Let me know if you need more help

Comment: That worked great! I used option 1 and put everything under my `AnswerString.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);` and pulled the correct answer using `String answerText = currentQ.getANSWER();` if anyone else want to know!